# How prove this integral $\int_0^{2\pi }{\frac{{{e^{\cos x}}\cos\left({\sin x}\right)}}{{p-\cos\left({y-x}\right)}}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, contour-integration

show that

> $$ \int\limits_0^{2\pi }{\frac{{{e^{\cos x}}\cos\left({\sin x}\right)}}{{p-\cos\left({y-x}\right)}}}dx =\frac{{2\pi }}{{\sqrt{{p^2}-1}}}\exp\left({\frac{{\cos y}}{{p+\sqrt{{p^2}-1}}}}\right)\cos\left({\frac{{\sin y}}{{p+\sqrt{{p^2}-1}}}}\right);\left({p > 1}\right) $$

I think this is nice integral,But I can't show it,Thank you

Comment: The Maple code $$int(exp(cos(x))*cos(sin(x))/(p-cos(y-x)), x = 0 .. 2*Pi)\,assuming\, p>1, y>0 $$ produces the output which can be seen [here](http://rapidshare.com/share/8490C9F08FC581051422AAACEF29973C).

Comment: $ \displaystyle e^{\cos x} \cos (\sin x) = \text{Re} \ e^{e^{ix}} $

Comment: @Pedro Tamaroff: Why did you delete the answer?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Observe that the numerator is simply the real part of $e^{e^{i x}}$.  Thus, the desired integral is simply the real part of the contour integral

$$2 i \oint_{|z|=1} dz \frac{e^z}{e^{-i y} z^2-2 p z + e^{i y}}$$

(This is derived by substituting $z=e^{i x}$, $dx = -i dz/z$, $\cos{x}=(z+z^{-1})/2$, $\sin{x}=(z-z^{-1})/(2 i)$, and doing a little algebra.)

The poles of the integrand are at $z_{\pm}=(p \pm \sqrt{p^2-1}) e^{i y}$, of which only $z_-$ is inside the unit circle (recall that $p \gt 1$).  The residue at this pole is simply

$$2 i\frac{e^{(p-\sqrt{p^2-1}) e^{i y}}}{-2 \sqrt{p^2-1}}$$

and the integral is therefore, by the residue theorem, $i 2 \pi$ times this residue, or

$$\frac{2 \pi}{\sqrt{p^2-1}} e^{(p-\sqrt{p^2-1}) e^{i y}}$$

We then take the real part of the above to get the sought-after integral.  Thus,

$$\int_0^{2 \pi} dx \frac{e^{\cos{x}} \cos{(\sin{x})}}{p-\cos{(y-x)}} = \frac{2 \pi}{\sqrt{p^2-1}} e^{\left (p-\sqrt{p^2-1}\right ) \cos{y}} \cos{\left [\left (p-\sqrt{p^2-1}\right ) \sin{y}\right ]} $$

as was to be shown.

Comment: Is this technique different from mine? It is exactly the idea in my answer.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal: Big difference is that mine is useful and yours is not.  Your idea, as I noted, beyond the fact that you sub $z=e^{i x}$, is wrong.

Comment: Thanks to the comment by Random variable.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal: what's that supposed to mean?  That I was only able to solve this problem because someone else had the same idea?  I never claimed it was a work of genius.  But, no, I did not give RV credit because I came up with that all by myself.  You have no idea how I solve my problems, so it is quite  presumptuous of you to post, on my answer, that I owe someone else credit.